# "TV": is it formal or informal?

Tags: writing, formality, acronyms

I would definitely say that the term *TV* is informal (while *television* is formal), however I have found "TV" in some formal compositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is somewhat more informal than *television*, but not very much so; while I'd certainly prefer *television* in most written texts, I'd not be shocked at reading *TV* either, perhaps not even in a scientific research paper. Others might disagree. In official documents, however, I strongly recommend *television*.

Comment: a technical paper may well include an abbreviations page defining TV (and other abbreviations) and then go on to use TV in the main body

Comment: @Jasper Loy, I think on the European side of the Atlantic, the word *refrigerator* has all but died out.